# Find value in table using characters?

Tags: lua

I have table with values, i want return all values from val table who have this characters in search_str value.

```
local items_array = {
'apple','app','hello', 'app21'
}

local function test(str)
for k , v in pairs(items_array) do
    print(string.match( str, v ), v)
    // print(string.match( str, ".*"..v..".*" )) // it's don't work
end
end
test('a') // but that implies apple , app , app21
// returned

nil apple
nil app
nil hello
nil app21
```

Comment: @Piglet Yes it's what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [string.find](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.find) or [string.match](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.match) to check wether your table element string comprises the searched string.

Please refer to the Lua manual for its very basics.

Comment: I updated my question code. If you don't know , string.find working only if finding word is full, like app == app. It's not working in my example.